# Scilab - How to compare between numbers

Tags: scilab

Assume

```
s1 = 'Yes';
s2 = 'No';
tf = strcmp(s1,s2)
```

If not equal, it will provide 0 else 1.

The following above example is to compare between strings. But I can't do the same with numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [comparison operators](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/less.html) for numbers:

```
n1 = 1;
n2 = 2;
tf = n1 == n2
```

If you really want a 0 and a 1 for the false and the true, you can use

```
tf = bool2s(n1 == n2)
```

Comment: This returns %F, not 0. Then again, it's not clear if the OP really wanted 0 and 1 as they named the variable tf.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a call to `bool2s` in case the OP really wanted 0 and 1